# Why GridView data is generated as links

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview

In a project written in vb.net I've problem with a GridView, that generates all data as links instead of plain text which i want it as. Look below to see an example of a table data generated by the grid:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$xxxx','$0')">2012-10-10</a></td>
```

My html:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="xxxx" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="False"></asp:GridView>`
```

vb code:

```
    Dim id As New ButtonField
    id.HeaderText = "id"
    id.DataTextField = "id"
    xxxx.Columns.Add(id)
    ....
    ....
    xxxx.DataSource = data
    xxxx.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    xxxx.EnableViewState = False
    xxxx.DataBind()
```

A note: when i alter text in RowDataBound event, the data generates correct in the grid, that is in plain text and not as links. Why is it generated as postback links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `ButtonField`, you might want to use a [BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx) instead:

```
Dim id as New BoundField
id.HeaderText = "id"
id.DataField = "id"
```

Comment: Now when you say it, is seems obvious. Thanks!